# Filter table rows based on multiple checkboxes value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi so i have a list of checkboxes of different countries. And i want to filter the rows based on the countries selected. My code filters rows correctly if there is one checkbox selected at one time but if i select multiple checkboxes it doesn't work. I want it to work in case if i select checkboxes of China, USA than it should show all rows containing china and USA as a country.

Where locations is an array containing countries values from selected checkboxes. I want to search it on multiple countries.

```
   $("#websiteTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().indexOf(locations)> -1);
            });
```

Here is my HTML table code

```
<table class="table table-striped border table-row-bordered table-row-gray-1000 border gy-7 gs-7">
                                    <thead style="background-color: #366687;">
                                    <tr class="fw-semibold fs-6 text-white border-bottom border-gray-200">
                                        <th>Logo</th>
                                        <th>Media Name</th>
                                        <th>Language</th>
                                        <th>Location</th>
                                        <th>Media Type</th>
                                        <th>Industry</th>
                                        <th>Potential Audience</th>
                                        <th>Screenshot</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="websiteTable">
                                    @foreach($websites as $website)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><img alt="Logo" src="assets/media/logos/merilogo.png" class="h-30px h-lg-35px" style="width: 90%" /></td>
                                            <td>{{$website->name}} <span style="display:block"><a href="{{$website->news_url}}" target="_blank">View Link</a></span></td>
                                            <td>{{$website->language}}</td>
                                            <td id="table-location">{{$website->country}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$website->type->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$website->category->name}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$website->potential_audience}}</td>
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-camera" style="
                                                                                            font-size: 19px;
                                                                                            color: #366687;
                                                                                            padding-left: 27PX;
                                              "></i></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img alt="Logo" src="assets/media/logos/merilogo.png" class="h-30px h-lg-35px" style="width: 90%" /></td>
                                        <td>{{$website->name}} <span style="display:block"><a href="{{$website->news_url}}" target="_blank">View Link</a></span></td>
                                        <td>{{$website->language}}</td>
                                        <td id="table-location">China</td>
                                        <td>{{$website->type->name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$website->category->name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$website->potential_audience}}</td>
                                        <td><i class="fa fa-camera" style="
                                                                                            font-size: 19px;
                                                                                            color: #366687;
                                                                                            padding-left: 27PX;
                                              "></i></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

And here is checkbox code. You can imagine that Checkboxes will have values like USA, China, Japan etc. I want to filter table that if user has selected only USA than only locations containing USA only should appear. And current code works fine with single selection. The issues arises when i select multiple locations like USA, China etc. It should show locations from USA and China both. I am unable to figure this path

```
<div class="card-body">
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-custom form-check-solid form-check-sm py-1">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="All" id="all_location"/>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="location-0">
                                            All
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    @foreach($countries as $country)
                                        <div class="form-check form-check-custom form-check-solid form-check-sm py-1">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="location[]" value="{{$country}}" id="location-{{$loop->iteration}}"/>
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="location-{{$loop->iteration}}">
                                                {{$country}}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach

                           
                                </div>
```

Comment: Including a relevant sample of your HTML would be much appreciated, in order that those trying to help aren't also having to guess your HTML in order to recreate your problem. If they do make guesses that - unfortunately - often leads to "*but my HTML is structured in a different way, so this doesn't work*," which results in frustration and further time being unnecessarily spent.

Comment: @DavidThomas thankyou for suggestion. I have updated the question. Can you please look into post now and suggest me a way! Appreciate it!

Comment: @DavidThomas My code works fine if in indexof i pass a single element but as i want to make it work on multiple locations, i want to pass a array in it and here the code breaks. This is the only issue!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you.

```js
function filterTable(myTable) {
  $(myTable + " tbody tr").filter(function() {
    let locations = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    
    if(locations.length) {
        locations = Array.from(locations).map(input => input.getAttribute('name'));
    } else {
        locations = [];
    }

    return locations.includes($(this).data("location").toLowerCase()) ? $(this).removeClass('none') : $(this).addClass('none');
  });
}

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {
    filterTable("#websiteTable");
});

$("#showAll").on("click",showAll);

function showAll() {
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").prop("checked",false);
  
  $("#websiteTable tbody tr").removeClass("none");
}
```

```css
#checker {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkers">
  <label>USA
    <input type="checkbox" name="usa" value="1">
  </label>
  <label>China
    <input type="checkbox" name="china" value="1">
  </label>
  <label>Panama
    <input type="checkbox" name="panama" value="1">
  </label>
  <label>India
    <input type="checkbox" name="india" value="1">
  </label>
  <button id="showAll" type="button">Show all</button>
</div>
<hr>
<table id="websiteTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Some number</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-location="Uruguay">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Uruguay</td>
      <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="Germany">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <td>4654</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="Germany">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
      <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="Panama">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Panama</td>
      <td>78788</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="USA">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="China">
      <td>6</td>
      <td>China</td>
      <td>46546</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="India">
      <td>7</td>
      <td>India</td>
      <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="Italy">
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
      <td>1222234</td>
    </tr>
  
    <tr data-location="Panama">
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Panama</td>
      <td>8877</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="Ghana">
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Ghana</td>
      <td>889</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-location="Sweeden">
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Sweeden</td>
      <td>654</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Some notes:

1. In order to make the search easier, each `tr` element within the body has been given a `data` attribute, which holds the country name. This makes it easier to search, and we don't have to dig through the contents of every cell of every row. The table in the example has only three columns and a small number of rows, but imagine having a table with dozens of columns and hundreds or thousands of rows.
2. Every checkbox has been given the name of the country it represents. The setup doesn't have to work like this - you could have a multiselect, for example, and the values would be ids of the countries (taken from a database)
3. Your original approach has been modified, to work like this.

```
function filterTable(myTable) {
 //...
}
```

First, everything is within a function. It doesn't have to be setup like this, but by doing it like this, you could easily detach this particular change event handler, should the need arise.

`myTable`, the argument of the function, is the id of your table.

```
    let locations = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    
    if(locations.length) {
        locations = Array.from(locations).map(input => input.getAttribute('name'));
    } else {
        locations = [];
    }
```

Next, we pickup all of the checked locations, and reduce the collection of checkboxes to an array of their names (countries). If nothing is checked, the array is empty.

```
    return locations.includes($(this).data("location").toLowerCase()) ? $(this).removeClass('none') : $(this).addClass('none');
```

Finally, we filter the rows with `includes` - if the current row's value of the `data-location` attribute is within the array of checked locations (that is to say, their names), that particular row will have its `none` class removed. If it's not within the array, the class will be assigned to it, removing it from view.

4. The `none` class has been introduced for simplicity, to toggle the visibility of the rows.
5. Perhaps unnecessarily, a button for toggling back the visibility of all of the rows has been introduced. Again, this is for simplicity - a solution making use of `location = []` in the filter would have worked just as well. However, if there are a lot of checkboxes, the button unchecks them all, and reverts the original visibility - surely faster in most cases, than to manually untick every single checkbox.
6. In order to toggle back the visibility, we need to both untick the checkboxes, and remove the `.none` class from the rows which have it.